# show images in html2pdf library

Tags: php, html2pdf

I have a table contains multiple rows and each row has an image.

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td style="">
          <img src="<?php echo $img_path; ?>" />
              <?php echo ucwords($name); ?>
       </td>
       <td style="">
          <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid;margin-left: 98px;">
              <?php echo $date; ?></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
          <?php echo $role; ?> 
            Signature
       </td>
       <td style="">
          Date
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible in HTML2PDF to show images as shown in html rather than using his built in functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
require('html2fpdf.php');
$pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$fp = fopen("sample.html","r");
$strContent = fread($fp, filesize("sample.html"));
fclose($fp);
$pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
$pdf->Output("sample.pdf");
echo "PDF file is generated successfully!";
?>
```

Alternatively, you may use TCPDF and can try [like this](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps)

```
$content='<img src="sample.jpg">';
$html = <<<EOD
$content
EOD;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
$pdf->Output("sample.pdf", 'F');
```

Comment: Their is an error on "Fatal error: Call to undefined method HTML2PDF::AddPage() "

Comment: have you included fpdf.php ??

Comment: download the complete zip from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/ it will work..

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version of library and configured as well :) , but he problem is that this library uses his own functions to render the images, Is their any way we provide his images in html and it display as it is?

Comment: You can check this http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php TCPDF is much easier and has lots of examples and will easily give you pdf files from <img> tag in your html

Comment: exactly I had explored this example, in this example it used his our functions and dimensions for rendering images but not form provided html

Comment: here example009.php for images, If we check it, no hmlt embeded images are rendered but using his own functions